# How to Implement Azure Data Facotry If Condition and/or Lookup Activity on Table

Tags: azure-data-factory

In the following Azure ADF pipeline I would like an IF Condition to query or Look up the table in the database that has been copied to SQLDB with Copy data activity **'Copy to SQLDB'**  and query a field called as_of_date in the database and execute the following True IF Condition, 'if as_of_date = 31/05/2023 (end of last month) then continue to Copy data activity **Copy to Lake From SQLDB**  IF False move to Stored Procedure Fail Process

I'm kind of speculating that I should use the IF Condition activity, I may well be better off using another Activity, your advice warmly welcomed.

[image]

I was think that a possible alternative approach would be to use a single Look up activity and execuate a simple CASE WHEN STATEMENT and if the field **as_of_date** has data continue to Copy data activity **Copy to Lake From SQLDB**  see image. Can someone show me how that is a good approach?

[image]

Comment: I think I'm going to need a Look up activity before the IF Condition activity, but I'm not sure. Any thoughts welcomed.

Comment: Your true/false conditions need to be activities inside the IF condition activity, not after the IF condition.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute the copy activity on successful completion of if activity and on failure of if activity, stored procedure will be executed. Instead give the activities inside true and false branches  of `if activity` respectively.
[image]

1. Enter the condition in expression text box of if activity
2. Give the activities to be executed when the condition is true inside the true case of if activity. Click the edit icon near True case and take the copy activity that needs to be executed on true case.
3. Similarly, inside false branch of if activity, give the execute stored procedure activity, by clicking the edit icon near False.